# Creating a jQuery Validate method that cheks for phone number OR specific text

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin on my forms. One section of my form allows the user to choose whether they would like to receive text message or email notifications. If the user chooses to get texts, I want the validator to check this input to make sure that the number is entered correctly.

If the user chooses to receive emails, I have the phone number input getting the value of 'Mobile not chosen.'

The problem is that when the form is submitted and the validation runs, it checks the phone input to see if a valid phone number format has been entered. Obviously, since 'Mobile not chosen' is not numeric, I get errors.

I'm working to add a custom method to check if there is a valid US phone number OR does 'Mobile not chosen' exist.

Could use your guys' help. Here's what it looks like so far:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("testPhone", function(phone_number, element) {
phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/) || phone_number.val('Mobile not chosen');
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You really need to fix your question to include the relevant HTML markup and your call to `.validate()`.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to test it, I think `phone_number` is already a string, so, `phone_number.val('Mobile not chosen')` wouldn't do what you're trying, val() gets the value from an input. Perhaps try:

```
phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/) || phone_number === 'Mobile not chosen';
```

or assuming the parameter `element` is the input field

```
phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/) || element.val() === 'Mobile not chosen';
```

Looking at the plugin mentioned though and that method, it's testing to see whether the input is optional first `this.optional(element)` so perhaps there's a way to just toggle the element to optional when a user enters their email address first.

Answer (score 0):

Until you show enough code in your OP, nobody can answer with great specificity.

There are two possible solutions...

1)  The `require_from_group` method as part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js).  This method will let you specify that only x fields are "required" out of a group of y fields.  See the source code of the file for usage.  Since I cannot see your HTML or `.validate()` method, I am unsure if this will work for you.

2)  [The `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) will allow you to dynamically change rules on your fields.  In your case, if the user chooses texts, call `.rules('add')` on the field to add the phone number rule and `.rules('remove')` to remove the email rule.  Then if the user chooses email, call `.rules('add')` to add the email rule and `.rules('remove')` to remove the phone number rule.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/